# Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode

Tags: reactjs

I have tried to add google map to my project and everything works good but i have following warning in my console but don't know why and how to fix it.

"Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

- Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
- If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: https://reactjs.org/link/derived-state

Please update the following components: Wrapper"

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker } from 'google-maps-react';
const Location = (props) => {
  const mapStyles = {
    width: '60%',
    height: '60%'
  }
  const {google} = props
return (
  
<div className="map-area">
  <h1>Znajdź nas!</h1>
  <Map
  google={google}
  zoom={13}
  initialCenter={{
    lat: 53.188,
    lng: 18.066
  }}
  style={mapStyles}
  >
    <Marker />
  </Map>
</div>);
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: ('MY_TOKEN')
})(Location)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem in the current version of `google-maps-react` and React's strict mode. See: https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/issues/476

You probably shouldn't disable strict mode, so you'll have to either fix the library yourself or wait for someone to do that, then upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

hear is the fixer ,
Step 1: go to node_modules > google-maps-react > GoogleApiComponent.js > {
change line no. 149 & 150 UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps --> componentDidUpdate
}

Step 2: then install  npm i patch-package
Step 3: add this line in pkg.json
"scripts": {

- "postinstall": "patch-package"
  }
  Step 4: then install npx patch-package package-name
  There you go just simple restart application and you are done